# KnockoutJs - How to "synchronize" subscriptions and click event?

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

Simple situation. I have form with textboxes, bound to observables. Observables has subscriptions to do some logic (server validation, whatever, just some ajax call).

There is also a button on form with some "save data" logic. Data should be saved only when all callbacks are finished.

Subscribtions are fired when value changed, mostly on focus lost, not just on every change.

Now you can simply type anything to textbox then immediately click on save button. What happens? Click event is called, and data are saved. But it is sometimes faster then subscribtion event is fired and server returns data.

How to "synchronize" click with "done" promise of subscriptions? I need to prevent to save data before everything is done. But there is no relation between subscription of textbox value and button. Everything is async, so I can't just call something like "wait for function" in click event. Other problem should be that subcription is fired later then click event.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to manage the button state -

```
<button data-bind="disable: serverSideCheckInProgress">Save Data</button>
```

Within your ajax call -

```
//declare serverSideCheckInProgress false on init

saveData = function(){
  serverSideCheckInProgress(true);
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function() {
    serverSideCheckInProgress(false);
  });
}
```

Comment: Already did, but subscription of textbox observable fires later then button is clicked. There is some delay. So button is enabled, user clicks and then knockout fires textbox sunscription as focus lost and value has changed. It is strange, but this way it works form me in this case.